# Proving an inequality of a function given its derivative's values

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f(x)$ be differentiable twice and for which it's true that $f(0) = f'(0) = 1$ and $f''(x) > \frac{1}{x^2 + 1}$ for all values of $x$. Prove that $\forall x \ge 1: f(x) > 2$.

---

I thought this might be solvable using Taylor's theorem. Around the point $0$, $f$ can be written as $f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + \frac{f''(0)}{2}x^2 + R(x)$ where $R(x)$ is the error term. This simplifies down to $f(x) = 1 + x + \frac{f''(0)}{2}x^2 + R(x)$ for which it's true that $f(x) = 1 + x + \frac{f''(0)}{2}x^2 + R(x) > 1 + x + \frac{f''(0)}{2}x^2 > 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2}$, therefore for $x\ge1$, $f(x) > 2$. Now, I'm very sure this is not how you solve this but it's the only thing I've been able to find any success with. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be solved with Taylor's theorem, but if you write
$$
f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + \frac{f''(0)}{2}x^2 + R_3(x)
$$
then nothing is known about the error term $R_3(x)$.

Better write
$$
f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + R_2(x)
$$
with the Lagrange form of the remainder:
$$
R_2(x) = \frac{f''(c)}{2}x^2 
$$
for some $c \in (0, x)$. Then $R_2(x) \ge \frac{1}{2(1+c^2)} x^2 > 0$ and therefore
$$
f(x) > f(0) + f'(0)x = 1+x
$$
for all $x > 0$, and in particular $f(x) > 2$ for $x \ge 1$.

Comment: Aha so this rephrases what I wrote as the function being (1+1) times differentiable and then the remainder is in Lagrange form, right?

Comment: @moxy: Yes, this is the Lagrangre remainder, only the degree of Taylor's formula is chosen differently.

Comment: I see. Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 5):

A problem of using a Taylor expansion is that we do not know whether $f$ is indefinitely differentiable.

Here is one approach. Integrating $f''(x)>\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ gives
$$ f'(x) > f'(0) + \int_0^x \frac{1}{t^2+1} \,dt = 1 + \tan^{-1}x. $$
Integrating this again yields that for $x\ge1$,
$$ f(x) > f(0) + \int_0^x 1+\tan^{-1}t \,dt > 1+x \ge 2. $$

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is differentiable $1 + 1 = 2$ times, so around the point $0$, $f$ can be written as $f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + \frac{f''(\xi)}{2}x^2$ for some $\xi \in (0, x)$. Because $f''(\xi) > \frac{1}{\xi^2 + 1}>0\iff \frac{f''(\xi)}{2}x^2 > \frac{x^2}{2(\xi^2 + 1)} > 0$, therefore $f(x) = 1 + x + \frac{f''(\xi)}{2}x^2 > 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2(\xi^2+1)} > 1 + x$. Then $\forall x\ge1$ it follows that $f(x) > 2$.